# TT job ad re-posted after I had a fly out - implications?

Tags: application, job-search, faculty-application, tenure-track, interview

I had a second interview for one US college 3 weeks ago and for another 2 weeks ago. The interviewers said they would be getting back to me in 2-4 weeks, depending on how things went internally. I have not received an email from them yet.

Last week, I found that the same job is posted multiple times in various job sites by the college. Does that mean the college is no longer interested in my profile and hence, searching for a better candidate?

In addition, I saw another job re-posted that I had been rejected from after a first-round interview. Can I apply for it again? Is there any remote possibility that the university will give me another chance (should I send them an email regarding this)?

In general, what can be surmised or gleaned from universities that repost jobs on boards after interviews have already started? Actually, I am planning to apply or re-apply for some positions according to that.

Comment: Here, is institute = college or university?

Comment: Second Round of Interview: Both of them are Colleges. Post edited.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Will keep in mind. Sorry for this one.  @AnonymousPhysicist

Comment: So I think there are many posts on timeline for TT interviews. The piece of this that might be helpful or new is explaining what goes on behind the scenes with job postings…

Comment: getting little idea about "what goes on behind the scenes with job postings" in the given context will be very helpful. @Dawn

Comment: And about: if I apply for the same position again with in a month, is there any remote chance that my candidacy will be evaluated again? @Dawn

Comment: No information can be gleaned.  There is no general answer.  Frequently but far from always reposting is only for bureaucratic or legal reasons.  Unless you need to know for some reason, just forget about it.  If you need to know, ask.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo that is an answer

Comment: @Dawn: I have previously been told that that is not an answer but rather an argument for voting to close for 'Depends on Individual Factors'

Comment: Just wondering what could be the possible reasons to keep the application portal open when the second round of interviews is going on/ended. That's it. @AlexanderWoo

Comment: Based on that I am planning to apply or re-apply in some colleges.

Comment: There is no way you should reapply. They have your application in the system still.

Comment: Thanks. I am also thinking so.

Comment: Any updates on this?  What happened to the position, did someone get hired?  This might be helpful to future readers on the implications of a TT job re-posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, especially, you can't really conclude anything definite. The procedures are too variable from university to university. And even more so for private colleges.

The reappearance of an ad could be anything from an administrative error to a desire to fish the pool a bit longer to see if a stronger candidate might appear. It doesn't imply rejection, though it might imply some reluctance.

For the other question on reapplying: yes you can reapply but don't expect a different outcome after a rejection. Lightning might strike, of course. It is possible that their needs have changed somewhat.

But the US has no national system and few constraints on college/university policy other than some restrictions on discrimination in hiring.

---

The "reappearance" of ads could actually be just the late appearance of ads previously paid for. I don't suggest that is the most likely scenario, but it is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful information. The ads are coming from LinkedIn which I think is unpaid one. How can the college then process other applications without rejecting the previous candidates? Because the interview process will take almost a month. I am just wondering about it.

Comment: My friends were able to apply for the same position even yesterday. :P